# When you minimize and maximize the application on the second screen, it always appears on the first screen where the application was started

Tags: qt

**Note:** If the window is not maximised, there is no problem

Here is a simple example of this wrong behaviour:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    
    QWidget*w=new QWidget();
    w->showMaximized();
    return app->exec();
}
```

I use Qt version 6.5.2.
I use Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
I work on the Windows 11 Pro edition operating system with the 22H2 version and the 22621.2134 OS build.